# template class with static template class member: how to define the static member

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class which itself contains a template class as static member. I can't find the correct syntax to define the static member as shown in the example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

template <typename B>
class Container
{
    std::list<B*> l;

    public:
    void add( B* b)
    {
        l.push_back(b);
    }
 };

template < typename A >
class Relais
{
    public:
        using RELAIS_TYPE = Relais<A>;
        static Container<RELAIS_TYPE> cont;

        void Do()
        {
            cont.add(this);
        }
};

// did not compile: Which is the correct syntax here...? 
Container<Relais<int>> Relais<int>::cont;

int main()
{
    Relais<int> r;
    r.Do();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, your code doesn't define `Container` anywhere, so I assumed that it's something like

```
template<typename Foo>                                                                                                                                                                                  
class Container{};
```

With that, you can use

```
template < typename A >
Container<typename Relais<A>::RELAIS_TYPE> Relais<A>::cont;
```

This says that for a template type `A`

- `cont` is a member of `Relais<A>`
- its type is `Container<typename Relais<A>::RELAIS_TYPE>`.

---

Full (building) code:

```
template<typename Foo>                                                                                                                                                                                  
class Container{};

template < typename A >
class Relais
{
    public:
        using RELAIS_TYPE = Relais<A>;
        static Container<RELAIS_TYPE> cont;

        void Do()
        {
            cont.add(this);
        }
};

template < typename A >
Container<typename Relais<A>::RELAIS_TYPE> Relais<A>::cont;

int main()
{
    Relais<int> r;
}
```

Comment: Added the missing code section in my example... copy paste...;)